# How to archive a file in jitterbit

Tags: jitterbit

I don't want to specify any specific file name in the source or target instead I would like to use a placeholder something like $filename.txt or [filename].txt

filename is a global variable in my operation and I need to move this file between folders.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "Archive" operation to move data from one location to another:

[image: Archive Operation]

[image: Assign to a global variable]

[image: Dynamically name the file]

Comment: How can I specify a filename for both the target and source if the filename is not known at the time of creating a source and target? For example, if I want to move a file that was recently processed in a different operation.

Comment: You can simply assign the file name to a global value (as you indicated in your original questions) and then use the global variable in place of the file name in target/source. I'll post screenshots as another response.